# Which quotes to use in string literal nested in another string

Tags: javascript, escaping, quote

I have in jQuery a function to change the html-content in a div, but the problem is that there is an onclick-function in it. I do not know which quote tags to use.

[q] = quote tag, that I do not know

```
$("#container div").html("<div id='overlay' onclick='goFullscreen([q]video1[q])'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape quotes:

> Quotes in strings should be preceded by a backslash. This allows the JavaScript interpreter to distinguish a quote within the string from the quotes that serve as string delimiters.

```
$("#container div").html("<div id='overlay' onclick=\"goFullscreen('video1')\"></div>");
//                                                  ^^             ^     ^ ^^
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rgn4pdcg/)

**OR**

```
$("#container div").html("<div id='overlay' onclick='goFullscreen(\"video1\")'></div>");
//                                                  ^             ^^      ^^
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rgn4pdcg/1/)

**Examples**

```
string1='It\'s five o\'clock!';
string2="<A HREF=\"index.htm\">";
```

> Alternatively, if your string includes single quotes only, then you can use double quotes as string delimiters, and vice versa. Here's an example:

```
string1="It's five o'clock!";
string2='<A HREF="index.htm">';
```

**UPDATE**

If `video1` is variable:

```
$("#container div").html("<div id='overlay' onclick=\"goFullscreen('" + video1 + "')\"></div>");
//                                                  ^^             ^^          ^ ^^ ^^
```

Comment: it gives back that the brackets between goFullscreen is empty :s

Comment: @DNA Is `video1` a variable or `string`?

Comment: @DNA Check the Demo added in answeer

Comment: it becomes a variable.

Comment: @DNA Check `UPDATE` in the answer

Comment: it is not a variable yet at the creation of the div, but it becomes one once the div is created.

Comment: it finally works. I forgot the slash after the ending bracket. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container div").html("<div id='overlay' onclick='goFullscreen(\"video1\")'></div>");
```

This way you can use any quote!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you wanted.

```
 $("#container div").html("<div id='overlay' onclick='goFullscreen(\"video1\")'></div>");
```